# Linear Search and Reverse Linear Search dont have same execution time

Tags: java, algorithm, search, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I have written code to implement linear search (starts from beginning of array) and Reverse Linear Search (starts from end of array). Now when I run the program on a sample of 1000 numbers, 1000 times (with different keys each time), this is the cumulative result.

**Total Time LS :814632**

**Total time RLS : 581558**

I wonder why do we have such a noticeble difference in execution times. I have used system.nanoTime() to check time. I think, considering a large distribution of 1000 (calling both functions 1000 times) , the time difference should not be so much because the key might fall in any of the 1000 indices.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, Exception {
            long val[][] = new long[1000][3];
             for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
             {
               val[i]=   testMethod();
             }
            long ls=0;
            long rls=0;
            long bls=0;
             for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
             {
                ls= ls+val[i][0];
                rls=rls+val[i][1];
                bls=bls+val[i][2];
             }

             System.out.println("Total Time LS :" + ls);
             System.out.println("Total time RLS : " + rls);
             System.out.println("Total time BLS : " + bls);
        }

    public static long[] testMethod()
    {   long[] val=new long[3];
        int[] arr= new int[1000];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=r.nextInt()%99999;
        }

        int i= Math.abs(r.nextInt()%1000);
        int key =arr[i] ;
     //   int key = arr[900];
    //    System.out.println(i);
        long sysTime1=System.nanoTime();
        int pos_LS= LS(arr,key);
        long sysTime2=System.nanoTime();
        long t=sysTime2-sysTime1;
        val[0]=t;
   //     System.out.println("LS Time : " + t);

         sysTime1=System.nanoTime();
        int pos_RLS=RLS(arr,key);
         sysTime2=System.nanoTime();
         t=sysTime2-sysTime1;
   //     System.out.println("RLS Time : " + t);
        val[1]=t;



        sysTime1=System.nanoTime();
       int pos_BLS=BLS(arr,key);
        sysTime2=System.nanoTime();
        t=sysTime2-sysTime1;
  //     System.out.println("BLS Time : " + t);
       val[2]=t;



        return val;
    }
    public static int LS(int[] arr, int key)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==key)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }



    public static int RLS(int[] arr, int key)
    {   
        for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {  
            if(arr[i]==key)
            {   
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int BLS(int[] arr, int key)
    {
        int len=arr.length;
        for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==key || arr[len-1-i]==key)
            {
                if(arr[i]==key)
                {
                    return i;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return len-i-1;
                }

            }
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

**2nd run : 
Total Time LS :868477
Total time RLS : 604649**

**3rd run :
Total Time LS :648266
Total time RLS : 765009**

**4th run :
Total Time LS :877037
Total time RLS : 619652**

Comment: Probably it depends on your `key`.

Comment: Even on such large distributions??

Comment: Well your 3rd run shows that your benchmark is invalid or the difference is not based on the code, but on the key and the distribution of the values in that array

Comment: @Matthias - I will use incremental keys and check.. So that there is no chance of a key being random.. (increase key index with each run of the method.. i.e, oth run, index =0 , 900th run, idex=900 ...).. This should give a better idea right?

Comment: @TheLostMind How about posting your whole scenario, including side conditions and stuff like this so we can answer why things happen and not guessing what you are trying to achieve here. However a benchmark which is showing the opposite result in a different run is not a good benchmark at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on your computer architecture and operating system. However, an overview can be done.

CPU run lots of processes in a time and CPU is only capable of executing commands. Most basic operations are [ALU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) operations inside CPU.

The data which will be processed is stored in computer memory which is [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) and [CPU caches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) in our case. CPU is run faster with its cached data. If the data is not in the cache so it fetches from memory(ram). A ram is a memory which has [random access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) time to data with its address.

**There may be no data in the cache**

There is no guarantee that the data to be processed  can be found in the cache. It is completely depend on other processes run on the CPU. This is our one obstacle. When and how many times CPU will not hit a cached data during Linear search.

**It is no guarantee that Linear Search will be done in a preemptive way**

Processes are not run in a single operations. CPU decides how many times a process run and then switches to other process. It is called [Context Swithcig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch). Furthermore, there are lots of [synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29) issues in the CPU during the processes are executed.

Above image shows a process life cycle inside CPU. So, it no guarantee that your linear search when run in CPU exactly.

[image]

The results that you show your question show that running times are variable as i explain. It is better to compare [BigO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) values of algorithms in both memory and timing analysis.

**See Also**

[Main Memory](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/8_MainMemory.html)

[Processes](http://minnie.tuhs.org/CompArch/Lectures/week08.html)

[Process State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state)

Comment: I highly doubt that traversing an array of 1000 elements will take long enough to suffer from context switching

Comment: I think, it is completely depend on processes which already run by CPU. There is no guarantee. What is your point about the running time differences in the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of details left unsaid in your experiment.

First off, you cannot conclude anything if you are generating random data sets every time. Best if you generate a huge data set once and always use those for those tests. Until then, we cannot rule out that linear search may have faced adversarial inputs. Remember that O(f(n)) notation only says that, *"its performance will not get any worse than this"* (in linear search's case, the linear function). It does not claim anything about the consistency of performance across several runs. (See footnote.)

Next, what do you mean by running a total? Do you add the execution times of each search? That's not a very good measure of statistics. It's best if you plot individual times and check the difference in the distribution of run times.

(Addendum: I think every programmer who does benchmarking should read [this post by Zed Shaw](http://zedshaw.com/essays/programmer_stats.html). An alternative to taking standard deviation as Shaw suggests is by looking at percentiles. Like standard deviation, it will allow you to rule out possible outliers that may skew your totals.)

**Footnote:** Performance analysis over multiple runs belongs to *amortized analysis*. Unlike the more common asymptotic analysis (which determines performance over *a single* run), however, it does not apply to all algorithms. Amortized algorithms and data structures usually perform additional house keeping tasks which "amortize" for the performance costs of other operations.

Comment: I add execution time each time the methods run (1000 in my case). So you want me to check 1Vs1 execution time ??

Comment: Nope. Not one-vs-one but rather set-vs-set. In a nutshell, get a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of the performances of LS and RLS and they shouldn't be too different (technically, _within an acceptable margin of error_).

Answer (score 1):

It fully depends on the `key` to be searched

Consider you are having this data `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

searching `2` with linear serch will take less time than reverse linear search

and searching `8` with reverse linear search will take less time than linear search

If you search `5` then both will give you same time

Comment: I think this nailed it, he should at least print the average search key - I wonder how far from N/2 it would be

Answer (score 1):

If you generate a new array, then run LS, then run RLS, then generate a new array and repeat, depending on the cache size on your computer you might experience the effect of the array being not in the cache for LS and in the cache for RLS. To verify if cache is influencing your test results you might run RLS first and LS after that (the LS could be faster now).

Answer (score 0):

My guess, it has everything to do with you compiler and how those arrays are implemented by them. The locations in your address space where those array indices are placed, how they are accessed, etc...

Again that's a guess I have no way of knowing that for sure. Another point worth noting that while those recorded times are consistently higher, they are never an order of magnitude higher. In an academic computer scientists point of view of runtime, those are both done in O(n) and those times reflect that.